# How can I auto-crop a pre-defined polygon shape from an image file?

Tags: python, image-processing, processing

Ideally using a Python library or processing.org, I need to import an image and then crop a predefined polygon area from this image using x,y coordinates (vertices).

Thanks.

Comment: I should add that I need to crop polygons with as many as 200 vertices. Most libraries only accommodate rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PythonMagick.](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/) Your question appears to be a cut-and-dry application of `crop` through specification of image geometry.

([More ImageMagick ports](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) and [documentation.](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php))

Answer (score 0):

Also check out [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

Though this is hardly library specific and almost every library should support this.